# What is the new Bootstrap 4 control-label class?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Visual Studio 2013, asp.net web app .Net 4.5

The Bootstrap 4 [migration doc](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) says:

> Renamed .control-label to .form-control-label.

But I can't find any such class in any bs 4 css file.
So what is the replacement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the explanation:

> Removed the unused `.form-control-label` class. If you did make use of this class, it was duplicate of the `.col-form-label` class that vertically centered a `<label>` with it’s associated input in horizontal form layouts.

> Renamed `.control-label` to `.col-form-label`.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#breaking

You were referring to the alpha docs which are **vastly outdated**. I mean, the alpha version of Bootstrap 4 is vastly outdated.